# Unknown column in on clause using aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an unknown column in the on clause in

```
SELECT course.title AS course, prereq.title AS prereq
FROM (SELECT title FROM course) AS course
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT title FROM course) AS prereq
  ON (course.course_id = prereq.course_id);
```

I also tried just with "USING (course_id)" but that gave the same error

Comment: You must add `course_id` to output lists in both subqueries.

Comment: You are doing a self-join on a table using a single column.  This is not going to produce anything interesting.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Formally:

```sql
SELECT course.title AS course, prereq.title AS prereq
FROM ( SELECT title, course_id
       FROM course ) AS course 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT title, course_id
                   FROM course ) AS prereq USING (course_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the sub-queries:

```
SELECT c.title AS course, p.title AS prereq
FROM course AS c
RIGHT OUTER JOIN course AS p
  ON c.course_id = p.course_id;
```

Note: Unnecessary subqueries make the optimizer work harder, which can affect the performance.

BTW, are you sure you want a `RIGHT JOIN` here? Looks more like a `LEFT JOIN` case.